# Disable magnifier globally when selecting text in Android 12

Tags: android-12, zooming, text-selection

Is there a way to disable the *magnifier* feature globally for all apps in **Android 12**? I found it annoying.

[image]

I've looked for a setting for this, but to no avail.

If it can't be done globally, maybe it's possible for, at least, **Firefox for Android** (or its fork)?